# Drawing on a DIB doesn't work

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi, visual-studio-2017

I'm working on a GUI class and I created a method which paints a bitmap on a window from an array of pixels.
I'd like to draw on that bitmap in the same method. Also, I use an off-screen DC to avoid flickering.

Here's my code :

```
int width(m_rect.right - m_rect.left), height(m_rect.bottom - m_rect.top); // m_rect is the RECT of the bitmap, initialized beforehand

BITMAPINFOHEADER bih = { 0 };
bih.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bih.biCompression = BI_RGB;
bih.biBitCount = 32;
bih.biPlanes = 1;
bih.biWidth = width; // = 100, for instance
bih.biHeight = height; // = 100, same here

HDC dc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc); // "hdc" is the DC of my window
HBITMAP bmp = CreateDIBitmap(hdc, &bih, CBM_INIT, m_data, &m_bmpInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS); // creates a 32-bit device-independent bitmap
HGDIOBJ oldObj = SelectObject(dc, bmp);

RECT r = { m_rect.left + 10, m_rect.top + 10, m_rect.right - 10, m_rect.bottom - 10 };
HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(0xff);
FillRect(dc, &r, brush); // this line doesn't work!
DeleteObject(brush);

BitBlt(hdc, m_rect.left, m_rect.top, width, height, dc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
SelectObject(dc, oldObj);
DeleteObject(bmp);
DeleteDC(dc);
```

The problem is that I can't draw anything on the bitmap. It is properly drawn on the screen, but I just can't draw on it. Same with other drawing functions : Rectangle, RoundRect, etc. Also, performance matters to me. The faster this code is, the happier I'll get. So if you have any advice on performance improvements please let me know.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's `m_rect.left` and `m_rect.top`? My guess is, you are painting outside the bitmap boundaries. Coordinates that fall into `dc` are within `ReCT{0, 0, width, height}`. You do it right in your `BitBlt` call, but not in your `FillRect` call.

Comment: Oh my gosh you were right!! m_rect.left and m_rect.top are the absolute coordinates of the top left corner of my bitmap. I can't believe I confused absolute and relative coordinates... Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: Since you care about speed, you might want to try using `CreateCompabitBitmap` instead of `CreateDiBitmap`. I haven't compared them in years, but at least when I did, compatible bitmaps were generally a fair amount faster.

Comment: Thank you for your post, but I think I'll have to use CreateDIBitmap anyway because I need to create my bitmap from an array of pixels, and this can't be done using CreateCompatibleBitmap. Is there another way to create a bitmap from raw pixel data?

Answer (score 0):

[CreateDIBitmap function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createdibitmap)
CreateDIBitmap function creates a compatible bitmap (DDB)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your answer and add some more explanations, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer